# How can I remove the -arch i386 flag when compiling C++ code in setup.py?

Tags: python, c++11, setup.py

I want to compile a C++ extension for Python. The problem is that the C++ program only works in x86_64 architecture but the default compile flags include -arch i386.

The setup.py looks like:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

integral_ext = Extension('mod._mod', 
            sources = ['wrap.cpp'],
            extra_compile_args = ['-mmacosx-version-min=10.7', '-std=c++11', '-stdlib=libc++'])

setup(
    ext_modules = [integral_ext],
)
```

During compiling, the terminal shows that the command is:

```
/usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -Wsign-compare -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/include/python3.6m -c wrap.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/wrap.o -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++
```

This would fail due to some static_assert code inside the C++ to require x86_64. 
I can successfully compile it by command line after removing the -arch i386 flag. However, I am writing a library for others to use and I want to make it simple so that users can install it by the standard way of running python3 setup.py install.

The bottom line is, I cannot change the C++ file and I want to do something inside this setup.py to make it compile. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error is gone when I include the following lines into the beginning of `setup.py`:

```
import os

os.environ['CFLAGS'] = '-fno-strict-aliasing -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -c'
os.environ['LDFLAGS'] = '-arch x86_64 '
```

And the compiling ouput when running `python3 setup.py install` is:

```
/usr/bin/clang -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -c -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/include/python3.6m -c qtwinclient_wrap.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/qtwinclient_wrap.o -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++
/usr/bin/clang++ -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -arch x86_64 -fno-strict-aliasing -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -c build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/qtwinclient_wrap.o -o build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/qtwinclient/_qtwinclient.cpython-36m-darwin.so -lc++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -Lqtwinclient -L/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/ -lqtwinclient_c -lpython3.6
clang: warning: build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/qtwinclient_wrap.o: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: -lc++: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: -lqtwinclient_c: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: -lpython3.6: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-bundle' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-undefined dynamic_lookup' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-g' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-fno-strict-aliasing' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-D NDEBUG' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-g' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-fwrapv' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-O3' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mmacosx-version-min=10.7' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-Lqtwinclient' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-L/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
```

The compilation is successful and but the many lines of warnings of `clang: warning: argument unused during compilation` still look ugly. If anyone can suggest how to get ride of the warnings that will be greatly appreciated.